# Is there a replacement to Console.ReadKey()?

Tags: c#, .net, input, keyboard

I need a replacement to `Console.ReadKey()`, so I can press multiple keys at once.

I need this is because I am making a Console ASCII Game Engine in C#. If I made a controllable player, I can only move either Up, down, left, and right. No diagonal movement at all, just because Console.ReadKey() allows one key at a time to be pressed.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

I'm okay with installing packages into my solution project

The function for key input is this (It's called every frame to check if the key is pressed):

```
public static char Key() // returns the pressed key in char
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyPress;
            if (Console.KeyAvailable) // will read the key only if it is pressed (can cause input lag on low frame rates)
            {
                keyPress = Console.ReadKey(true);
                return char.ToUpper(keyPress.KeyChar);
            }
            return default;
        }
```

Comment: Console isn't really a great environment for games. Any particular reason you chose that?

Comment: Well, I wanted an easy way to make an ASCII Game Engine, which replaces pixels with letters, numbers, and symbols. I thought it'd be fun to see indie games being made in ASCII and see how developers handle the graphical limitations of making games in Console C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better replacement! Just install NuGet Package called EZInput which will allow for better controls that inputting one key at a time.

I tried finding examples and documentation of EZinput online, couldn't find anything. I learned how to use it on my own. Easy, just type in EzInput and dot in the code and it will show all the things it has to offer.

if you want to press W to do something here is what you're supposed to do:

```
if (EZInput.Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(EZInput.Key.W))
{
    // Do something...
}
```

But it's best to type `using EZInput;` so that you don't need to type in the name every time.

Comment: that's great. What would make your answer even better for others (and likely get you more upvotes) is a) linking to resources about EZInput and b) showing a quick code example of how you've used it to do what you need.

Comment: I tried finding examples and documentation of EZinput online, couldn't find anything. I learned how to use it on my own. Easy, just type in EzInput and dot in the code and it will show all the things it has to offer.

Comment: That's not the point. The best StackOverflow answers contain usable examples that answer the specific question, rather than just a vague "use this library, it's great" instruction. Otherwise it's just likely to lead to more questions from people along the lines of "I tried to use EZInput to solve the same problem as in  Ali107's question, but it's not working...what did I do wrong?" Far more useful to just show people what you did, to begin with. And also if there's no online documentation for this library you could at least link to its entry on Nuget.org (so there's no ambiguity).